# Como chamar um método das views no html?

Tags: html, python, django, django-templates

Eu criei o seguinte método no ficheiro views.py:

```
def home(request):
   name = 'Jacinto'
   args = {'myName' : name}
   return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)
```

Eu quero agora chamar esta função que me redireciona para o ficheiro home.html no seguinte código html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="{% home %}">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Eu tentei usar {% home %} e já tentei também usar o caminho especifico do ficheiro, mas dá-me um erro de renderização, pois estou a usar um {% extend base.html %} e a navbar está afetada para eu a puder modificar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma view que renderiza um template da seguinte forma:

**urls.py** - Em suas urls, crie a rota que chama a view e de um name (esse nome que você vai chamar do template:

```
url(r'^accounts/home', views.home, name='home'),
```

**views.py** - Em seguida, crie a view e os atributos do contexto:

```
def home(request):
   context = {'name' : "Fabimetabi"}
   return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', context)
```

**accounts/home.html** - Agora no template, você chama o name da sua view criada no urls.py dessa forma:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

## Urls com Namespaces

Você também pode usar os [Namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names), para organizar melhor suas rotas.
Dentro do seu app, você cria um arquivo chamado **urls.py** também.

```
url(r'^home', views.home, name='home'),
```

E dentro do urls.py do seu projeto, você agrupa o conjunto de urls do seu app dessa forma:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
```

Por fim, em seu template você chama a url passando o namespace.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:home' %}">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Isso deixa o código e as chamadas de url no template mais organizadas. Se você tiver outros apps no menu ficaria dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'videos:home' %}">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Cadastrar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mais um para o `namespace`, não conhecia. ++

Answer (score 2):

Seria melhor vc criar o link no arquivo de url:

```
url(r'^accounts/home', views.home, name='home'),
```

Na view home vc renderiza o template.
E chama o link no html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
```

O nome 'home' no link é o name q vc definiu na url.